# Error compiling the BLLIP Parser for Mac

Tags: parsing, charniak-parser

as a newbie with NLTK, I was trying to parse sentence into different phrases (say, NP,VP,ADJP...) and choose the ones that I wanted for further analysis. I chose to use stat_parser, however, it was so slow. Then I found something here ([Quick NLTK parse into syntax tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363145/quick-nltk-parse-into-syntax-tree)), which shows what I want to do. The problem is I can not install bllip-parser with all methods I can find online (macports etc.). When I tried to make files as I was told in README, it shows the following error:

```
In file included from best-parses.cc:50:
./popen.h:25:10: fatal error: 'ext/stdio_filebuf.h' file not found
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [best-parses.o] Error 1
make: *** [reranker-runtime] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me about this error or tell me is there any other better way to do parsing using NLTK? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, BLLIP Parser [doesn't compile by default on Mac OS X Mavericks](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/issues/19). Fortunately, Jim White has a [branch of the parser](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/pull/20) with [instructions for how to compile on Mac OS X](https://github.com/jimwhite/bllip-parser/blob/BLLIP_FOR_MACOS/Makefile.mac). Here's a [direct download link](https://github.com/jimwhite/bllip-parser/archive/BLLIP_FOR_MACOS.zip) for his branch.

By the way, I should clarify that BLLIP Parser is separate project from NLTK. The above instructions are just for installing BLLIP Parser. As of version 3.0.2, NLTK provides an interface to BLLIP Parser with the [`nltk.parse.bllip`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#module-nltk.parse.bllip) module.